# Why isn’t the chai.js library available as tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

When I was posting a question related to the chai testing framework, I tried to add a chai.js tag to the question but couldn't find it.

I'm curious about why the popular unit testing library isn’t added as a tag in SO.

Comment: I mean this one https://www.chaijs.com/

Comment: @Robert Longson I am able to see it in desktop version but when I open SO in mobile browser it wasn't found

Answer (score 11):

It's already available. It's tagged [chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chai) which is described as

> a BDD/TDD assertion library for Node.js and the browser that can be used with any Javascript testing framework.

If you want to search for tags, go to the https://stackoverflow.com/tags page by clicking on the Tags link on the left (assuming you haven't hidden the left panel) and type in something, in this case chai.

Alternatively just typing chai in the tag area when you asked a question would have suggested it as a pre-existing tag.